# Recactjs autocomplete component gives error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new at Reactjs. I am trying to reuse [this kind of](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-frost-n2hzp) ready autocomplete select component in my app as well as in the given link it gives this error for anything this not found in the input box. To see the error just type xyz and press enter and check error in the console:-

> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be
>   uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to
>   uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More
>   info:

After searching this error I found that when any uninitialized state changes it throws this warning. But in this code, I can see all states are initialized. I don't understand why is it happening? Anyway, I am new to React so I must miss something. Please let me know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because inside the first conditional of the `onKeyDown` handler it's setting the state for `userInput` doing:

```
filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion]
```

However, if no suggested matches are made, the array `filteredSuggestions` will be empty and `activeSuggestion` will be `0` which will result in an `undefined` value for `userInput`.

It's like saying:

```js
const mySuggestions = [];
let choice = 0;

console.log(mySuggestions[choice]); // undefined
```

[Controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) should always have a value, `undefined` is not a value. That's why React is complaining.

One way to fix this, is by using [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) for the `value` of the  element:

```
<input
  type="text"
  onChange={onChange}
  onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
  value={userInput || ""}
/>
```

This basically translates to:

"If `userInput` is something, use whatever value it has, otherwise use an empty string".